# unused argument in r for monte carlo t test

Tags: r, montecarlo

I need help, I am doing t test using monte carlo metod but the results shows

> Error in t.test(x, alternative = "greater", mu = 500) :    unused
>   arguments (alternative = "greater", mu = 500).

Below is my code

```
#Compute an empirical probability of type I using Monte Carlo Method
# m is number of replicates
n <- 20
alpha <- .05
mu0 <-500
sigma <- 100
m <- 10000
p <- numeric(m)
for (j in 1:m){
  x <- rnorm(n, mu0, sigma)
  ttest <- t.test(x, alternative="greater", mu=500)
  p[j] <-ttest$p.value

}
p.hat <- mean(p < alpha)
se.hat <-sqrt(p.hat*(1-p.hat)/m)
print(c(p.hat, se.hat))
```

Comment: what is `find("t.test")` ?  you've probably got a different function masking `stats::t.test` ...

Comment: Try: `ttest <- stats::t.test(x, alternative="greater", mu=500)`

Comment: I don't get the error when I run your code. You can provide the results of `sessionInfo()` to see what you have loaded.

Comment: Thanks Gary and Ben! It's working now!!!